# Detect when a game is launched and when it is exited

Tags: process

I am trying to limit my computer master volume when my child is playing a game on it, then revert to previous volume. The code below isn't working to detect when a game is running nor when it stops.

`Imports CoreAudioApi`
    `Private GameOn As Boolean = False Private Game As New Process Private Prevol As Integer Private SVol As Single Private MuteStatus As Boolean Private ReadOnly DevEnum As New MMDeviceEnumerator() Private WithEvents Device As MMDevice = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia)`

```
Private Sub DisplayTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
        If GameOn = False Then
            For Each Proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
                Dim PName As String = Proc.ProcessName.ToLower
                If PName.Contains("openjdk") Or PName.Contains("java") Or PName.Contains("roblox") Or PName.Contains("genshin") Or PName.Contains("sims") Then
                    GameOn = True
                    If GetVol() > 20 Then
                        Prevol = GetVol()
                        SetVol(20)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
 End Sub
```

``    Private Sub GameClose(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
GameOn = False
SetVol(Prevol)
End Sub
Public Function GetVol() As Integer        'Function to read current volume setting
Dim MasterMinimum As Integer = 0
Dim Vol As Integer = 0
With Device.AudioEndpointVolume
Vol = CInt(.MasterVolumeLevelScalar * 100)
If Vol < MasterMinimum Then
Vol = CInt(MasterMinimum / 100.0F)
End If
End With
Return Vol
End Function

```
Public Sub SetVol(ByVal SVol As Single)
    Device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = SVol / 100.0F
End Sub

Private Function GetMute() As Boolean
    Return Device.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute
End Function

Private Sub SetMute(ByVal bMute As Boolean)
    If bMute = GetMute() Then Exit Sub
    Device.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = bMute
End Sub `
```